# Object mirrors about component axis rather then main model axis

Tags: mirror

I'm trying to mirror a component object about the main model's X axis, however when I add a mirror modifier the object mirrors about it's own axis. I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just use the "Mirror Object" field in the Mirror modifier:

[image]

Should give you the result you want:

[image]

If not, you might need to apply rotation on the object you want to mirror.

Comment: Thanks, I'd not defined the mirror object correctly!